# ngx-paypal don't work with production build

Tags: angular, paypal

In my Angular6 application I'm using

```
"ngx-paypal": "^6.2.0"
```

My code is

```
<ngx-paypal [config]="payPalConfig" ></ngx-paypal>
```

in the template where

```
this.payPalConfig = {
  currency: 'EUR',
  clientId: 'sb',
  advanced: {
    commit: 'true'
  },
  style: {
    label: 'paypal'
  },
  onApprove: (data, actions) => {
    actions.order.get().then(details => {
      this.salvaOrdine();
      console.log('onApprove - you can get full order details inside onApprove: ', details);
    });

  },
};
```

Everything works fine as long as I compile my app in development

```
ng build
```

[image]

but when I compile my app for production

```
ng build --prod
```

ngx-paypal doesn't show anything and there insn't any message in the F12 console.

Did I miss anything in  payPalConfig structure?

Comment: I've never used that library, but I assume that for production use your `clientId` shouldn't be set as `sb`. I think that is some kind of test value, just to see if this will be working on dev environments.

Comment: Even if I use the actual read clientId nothing changes.   clientId: 'AeY17r8cnmQMmokgRTaqfyierrj6Xd-CLyE7...............................................',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mgx-paypal conflicts with one of these build parameters (**angular.json**)

```
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
```

I've removed them all and now works